# How to fetch from Mysql something that has date for this week (from this monday till sunday)

Tags: mysql, date

I've got table with tickets in DB:

- name
- deadline

deadline is in DATE format. So how can I fetch only those tickets for current week (from monday till sunday) using plain MYSQL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE YEARWEEK(date_column) = YEARWEEK(NOW())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `YEARWEEK`

`YEARWEEK(date)`, `YEARWEEK(date,mode)`

Returns year and week for a date. The mode argument works exactly like the mode argument to `WEEK()`. The year in the result may be different from the year in the date argument for the first and the last week of the year.

Try below :

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table_name
WHERE YEARWEEK(deadline) = YEARWEEK(curdate())
```